# Accessing ioArgs from callback functions

Tags: dojo

I'm upgrading a bunch of old dojo to 1.8. For our ajax request handling we've got a decorator (well, function wrapper) that will perform redirects in certain cases based on the response content, for example:

```
// Decorator func:
var redirectDecorator = function(func) {
    var f = function(data, ioArgs) {
        if(data.redirect) {
            // A manual location redirect:
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        if(data.redirect_xhr) {
            // clone ioArgs, spawn new request to follow redirect etc
            // <snip>
        } else {
            func(response);
        }
    }
    return f;
}

// Used like so:

dojo.xhrPost({
    url: url
    handleAs: "json",
    form: form,
    load: redirectDecorator(function(data, ioArgs) {
        // do stuff
    })
});
```

Now, in dojo 1.8 (the [dojo/request/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr) module) `xhr()` returns a `Deferred` for chaining and the callbacks are only supplied the `data` argument (no `ioArgs` - apparently these are attached to the promise - see http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12126).

In other words, the above ajax call becomes:

```
xhr.post(url, {
    handleAs: "json",
    form: form
}).then(function(data) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Problem is, I can no longer wrap the anonymous function because `ioArgs` are not supplied. Inspecting the deferred (by breaking the chaining) doesn't appear to work either and would require more re-engineering than I'd like.

Any ideas?

---

Thanks Ken (for your help at #dojo too). To elaborate, the solution is to use `dojo/request` and use the `.response` deferred promise instead, which provides the necessary info:

```
// Decorator func:
var redirectDecorator = function(func) {
    var f = function(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        if(data.redirect) {
            // A manual location redirect:
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        if(data.redirect_xhr) {
            request(data.redirect_xhr, response.options).then(func);
        } // more conditions follow.
    }
    return f;
}

request.post(url, {
    handleAs: "json",
    form: form
}).response.then(redirectDecorator(function(response) { // <-- note .response.then(
    // do stuff where data is response.data
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises returned from `dojo/request` are actually objects with an additional `response` promise that provides more information.  See the following places for information:

- http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/08/21/introducing-dojorequest/
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request.html
- http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/ajax/